# Where is Authorisation code stored in Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I use JWT token store for OAuth tokens to achieve stateless calls. I can understand that access token and refresh tokens are JWT tokens. But I Authorisation code is not JWT. Where is it stored in the server, I know its temporary. But where does it stored and can we store this token alone in DB to avoid single point of failure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where Authorization Code is stored will depend on what implementation of `AuthorizationCodeServices` is used in `AuthorizationTokenGranter` and `AuthorizationEndpoint`

If `JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices` is used, then Authorization code will be stored in a table named `oauth_code`.

If `InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices` is used, then Authorization code will be stored in a `ConcurrentHashMap` in memory.